# How do I create a bridge table? Do I create two primary keys and two foreign keys?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I have a table that I want to make which is a bridge table for teacher and class table. This is the ERD

[image]

I initially thought I'm going to create this table by

```
CREATE TABLE class_teacher
(
    teacher_id number(3),
    class_id number(2),

    CONSTRAINT class_teacher_pk 
        PRIMARY KEY(teacher_id, class_id),
    CONSTRAINT class_teacher_teacher_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY(teacher_id) REFERENCES teacher(teacher_id),
    CONSTRAINT class_teacher_class_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY(class_id) REFERENCES class(class_id)
);
```

But on the web I see people just having two foreign keys and no primary key, or table with no foreign key and having a primary key for two columns.

Am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: Your method is fine, assume the other two tables are already created.

Comment: This type of schema facilitates a many-to-many relationship between Teachers and Classes, which makes sense if a Teacher can teach multiple Classes, and a Class can have multiple Teachers. If that is the case, then this is a common and useful schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing it incorrectly?

No, it looks correct.

Although I would question the size of the numeric data types as you are restricted to only have 1999 teachers and 199 classes (including negative numbers); this may be enough for immediate use but after several years when classes get re-organised or when the syllabus is re-written and new classes are created then you may run out of primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Does `create` statement returns any error? Otherwise you should be good.

Try to insert some data in all 3 tables and run some `delete` statements to see how it goes.